# Is it possible to use bash parameter expansion in Makefile?

Tags: bash, make

My Makefile:

```
FULL_VERSION ?= 1.2.3
MINOR_VERSION := $(shell echo "${FULL_VERSION%.*}")

test:
    echo $(MINOR_VERSION)
```

Running `make test` gives nothing, I want to get `1.2`.

I know I can get it via sed/grep but I'm looking for a more elegant solution, seems there's nothing simpler than bash parameter expansion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd need to first store the value in a shell variable:

```
MINOR_VERSION := $(shell v='$(FULL_VERSION)'; echo "$${v%.*}")
```

(assuming `$(FULL_VERSION)` doesn't contain single quotes)

Now that calls `sh`, not `bash`. `${var%pattern}` is a standard `sh` operator (comes from `ksh`).

If you wanted to use `bash`-specific operators, you'd need to tell `make` to call `bash` instead of `sh` with

```
SHELL = bash
```

Beware however that many systems don't have `bash` installed by default which would make your Makefile non-portable (but then, some systems don't have GNU `make` either and you're already using some GNUisms there)).

Comment: Although @uzsolt answer is also great because native, I prefer this one because sometimes it can be a non-semantic versioning, e.g. 1.2 instead of 1.2.3. Anyway, I didn't know that you can use single quotes to pass through Makefile vars

Comment: what if the variable expansion occurs in the shell script?  I'm getting "warning: undefined variables" since its not expanding from the Makefile.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with builtin functions (assume you're using GNU make):

```
VER=1.2.3
MINORVERTMP=$(subst ., ,${VER})
MINORVER=$(word 1,${MINORVERTMP}).$(word 2,${MINORVERTMP})


all:
    @echo ${MINORVER}
```

If you can use [`bmake` (BSD make)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make) can have more (and maybe simplier) possibilities:

```
VER=1.2.3

all: test1 test2

test1:
    # simple regular expression-based replace like sed
    @echo $@: ${VER:C,([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*).*,\1.\2,}

test2:
    # replace all dot to spaces (S),
    # print first and second element (:[1..2])
    # with dot separator (ts.)
    @echo $@: ${VER:S,., ,g:[1..2]:ts.}
```